# Prime function doesn't work in a composite number (4)

Tags: python, function, primes

I ran the following code:

```
def isprime(number):
    prime=True
    result=""
    for i in range(2, number//2):
        if number%i==0:
            prime=False
            break
    if(bool(prime)):
        result="Prime"
    else:
        result="Not prime"
    return  result
```

number is given to the function before.
I ran it and entered number=4, but it returned Prime
Can you help me? I started learning python only a few hours ago.

Comment: Please fix the code indentation in the question.  It's not clear what code is supposed to be part of the function and what isn't.

Comment: `range(2, number//2)` goes from `2` to `number//2 - 1`, which means it does not include number `2`. Anyway, you should learn how to use a debugger to see what is happening line-by-line.

Comment: `prime` is already a `bool`; there's no reason to call `bool` to get a Boolean value from it.

Comment: And there's really no reason (aside from poorly constructed assignments) for your function to return `str` variables that serve as proxies for proper Boolean values. Just return `prime` itself, not a string selected according to its value.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's be clear this is a programming problem, not a Python problem -- your algorithm would fail in any computer language.  Combining all the suggestions in the comments, plus a couple of additional optimizations, we come up with something like:

```
def isprime(number):
    if number < 2:
        return False

    if number % 2 == 0:
        return number == 2

    for divisor in range(3, int(number ** 0.5) + 1, 2):
        if number % divisor == 0:
            return False

    return True

if isprime(int(input("Enter a number: "))):
    print("Prime")
else:
    print("Not prime")
```